# Minimum value of function $f(x, y)$ if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and no other conditions are given

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I got this problem that's been bugging me. For a quick info, I'm a 12th grader in Indonesia. The problem was given by my teacher to evaluate my understanding on inequalities. Here is the problem:

> If $x$ and $y$ are both real numbers, what is the minimum value of the following function?
>
> $$\sqrt {4+y^2} + \sqrt {(x-2)^2 +(2-y)^2} + \sqrt{(4-x)^2 + 1}$$

My teacher told me to use either the Schwarz inequality or the RMS-AM-GM-HM inequality. I think that you're supposed to take the inequality to find the combination of $(x, y)$ where the inequality becomes equality. But other than that, I have no idea to proceed.

Thanks for anyone who has reserved their time to clarify this problem.

EDIT :
I've solved this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know Minkowski inequality or if you need to use only those inequalities you mentioned. Though, it may help, since you're dealing with a sum of norms.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think I've got the answer by using just Schwarzy inequality.

Comment: Would you post it, please? I'm just curious to know how it was solved :)

Comment: Please feel free to correct my work if I'm wrong. I'm just learning, after all.

Comment: That's exactly the Minkowski inequality I was talking about (or triangular inequality, if you prefer). No wonder you call it Schwarz inequality since it's a direct consequence of that, but with Schwarz inequality I think of $| \langlea,b \rangle | \leq \| a \| \| b \| $. Btw, your reasoning is correct in how it helps to find a lower bound for the function. Though you need to find a couple of values for which the minimum is attained to prove it is really a minimum. Otherwise it may be just that the function is always $\geq 5$ but its minimum is higher.

Comment: @moo : Yes, I've checked my answer with Wolfram Alpha. That's why I feel confident in my answer. Ok then, I think that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the vector form of Schwarzy's inequality, I find that :
$$\sqrt {4+y^2} + \sqrt {(x-2)^2 +(2-y)^2} + \sqrt{(4-x)^2 + 1}$$
can be broken down to :
$$\sqrt {2^2+y^2} + \sqrt {(x-2)^2 +(2-y)^2} + \sqrt{(4-x)^2 + 1^2} \ge{} \sqrt{(2 + x - 2 + 4 -x)^2 + (y + 2 - y +1)^2}$$ which can then be simplified to : $$\sqrt{4^2 + 3^2}$$ which is equal to 5.

Comment: As I've told in another comment, you only proved that $f(x,y) \geq5$, not that it's a minimum. Even if the correct is right in this case, you still have to prove it. You provided a lower bound and that's ok, now you need to prove that it's **attained** and, thus, it's a minimum. That means you have to find $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f(x_0,y_0)=5$. Else, it could just be a simple lower bound.

Comment: In fact, the bound derived in the answer is not attainable. The function has a local minimum at $(3,1)$ and has a value of $\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{2}>5$.